# Instal pip lxml on windows server 2012

Tags: python, pip, lxml, windows-server-2012

How do i install `lxml` on windows server 2012?
It gave me a `failed with error code 1` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need MS C++ Compiler, if you do not have it, download lxml on

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.7.3

and install with file which matches with your py version.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works... also i ran cmd and `cd` to the dir where the MS C++ download file was saved then run `msiexec /i [name ofe the MS C++ downloaded].msi` on administrator CMD.